# NextJS Googlebot an unexptected error has occurred

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, googlebot, next.js, google-search-console

We have developed a site SSR using NextJS. All works fine in differents desktop and mobile browsers but when I try to see my site as google see it, using the "fetch and render" functionality of Google Search Console, I obtain as response "An unexpected error has ocurred".

I have a script at the site to listen javascript errors and send it to Google Analytics, and no errors are received when googlebot visit the site. Also I see the log of the app and there aren't errors.

Do you know what could be the issue? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## Updated for March 2020

> Googlebot will now be “evergreen,” which means the crawler will always be up-to-date on the latest version of Chromium, the open source browser that Google's popular Chrome web browser is built on. Chrome 74. Googlebot has been updated to support Chromium rendering engine version 74.

[Quote from here](https://searchengineland.com/google-will-ensure-googlebot-runs-the-latest-version-of-chromium-316534)

You can view all of the GoogleBot UserAgents [here](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/10/updating-user-agent-of-googlebot.html) or download Chromium [here](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium).

Answer (score 1):

Google bot is made on the latest version of [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium). So, you are probably using some syntax not supported by this version.